# IDE For Objective-C On Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux, ide

I'm learning Objective-C and i would like to know where i can found a IDE for Objective-C on Linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two different IDEs provided with GNUstep, I prefer [ProjectManager](http://home.gna.org/pmanager/) but there's also [ProjectCenter](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ProjectCenter). While neither has been released in a while, the state in VCS is much better than the date of the last release would lead you to believe :-).

Comment: I've been having problems getting ProjectCenter to work under Ubuntu. Is this because it's a .app file? I would go with ProjectManager, but the latest release is over 3 years old now...

Comment: @Holland what's the problem? They should both be .apps, that's how GNUstep works.

Comment: ProjectManager won't compile due to it not being able to fine common.make, aggregate.make and a third makefile which I can't remember. I have gnustep installed, along with gnumake. Do you know of a way for the makefile to locate the proper files? I know next to nothing about makefiles.

Comment: You might have to source GNUstep.sh - check the GNUstep documentation

Answer (score 3):

Honestly when it comes to doing Objective-C and you have access to a Mac, Xcode is your best bet but here's what I know would be close enough on a Linux box:

- [Project Center](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/ProjectCenter.html)
- [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)
- And not sure if there's a plugin for it, but [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is a fairly good IDE.

Comment: Yeah, um Cocotron is definitely not an IDE. It is an implementation of some of the Cocoa libraries.

Answer (score 3):

What do you want out of an IDE?  Emacs has a very good Objective-C mode, and good integration to parse build errors from GCC and also debug with GDB.  It would be a good IDE for most tasks, unless you really want a GUI builder.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at [the latest FreeBSD release](http://www.freebsd.org/releases/9.0R/announce.html), which incorporates Clang, a rival of gcc with a BSD licence instead of a GPL licence.